# Throwing ExternalException with custom HResult

Tags: c#, exception

I wanted to throw an exception with a custom HResult or errorCode so i have tried the ExternalException

#### Code

```
throw new ExternalException("Login required", 0x6acfc5);
```

However when i catch the exception and look to it's `HResult`, i find that it is not `0x6acfc5` but another strange negative number.

Comment: So, what is the negative number?

Comment: A console app that just puts your code in a `try` block, and prints out `Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode.ToString("X"));` in a `catch` block shows `6ACFC5`.  What are you seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExternalException("Login required", 0x6acfc5)
```

this constructor accept errorCode as second parameter, and it is in  `System.Int32`

when you give value as `0x6acfc5` it will convert to int value `7000005`, that's what you see as `HResult`

if you call `ex.HResult.ToString("X")` you will get `6ACFC5`

**Note:** `ToString("X")` convert int value to  a hexadecimal string